# confusing mouseout behavior

Tags: jquery, mouseout

Given the following unordered list, I want the list to disappear on a mouseout event.

Note that when this line  *$(this).css ('display','none')*; is commented out the behavior is just as I expect with the background changing colors when the mouse is moved in and out of the list.

However, when I uncomment that line I would expect the UL to disappear on a **mouseout** event.  Instead, it disappears as soon as the mouse is moved **into** the list.

I've been at this for six hours.  what am I missing?

Thanks,

Mac

```
    <style type="text/css">

    * {
        color: navy;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    ul, li {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    ul#member {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 0px;
        //clear: left;
        border: 1px solid red;
        padding: 4px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: block;
        line-height:1.5;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //alert ('jQuery Is Alive and Well');

     $('ul#member').mouseover (function() {
          $(this).css('background-color','silver');
        });

     $('ul#member').mouseout (function(){
            $(this).css('background-color','gray');
           // $(this).css ('display','none');

        });
    }); //end of document ready
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <ul id='member'>
       <li>Change Villages ID#</li>
       <li>Change Address</li>
       <li>Changes Phone Numbers</li>
       <li>Change Name</li>
    </ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this what you have? http://jsfiddle.net/bTh3A/2/

Comment: I've made a few corrections to your jQuery and HTML (a few missing semicolons and your last `</li>` tag was messed up)

Answer (score 0):

You want to select the individual `li` tags for the css modifying, like so:

```
$('ul#member li')

<ul id='member'>
    <li>Change Villages ID#</li>
    <li>Change Address</li>
    <li>Changes Phone Numbers</li>
    <li>Change Name</li>
</ul>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bTh3A/6/

Comment: Heh, that was copied from his original question, fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

problem here is with your `mouseover()\mouseout()` function

```
`mouseover` fires when the pointer moves into the child element as well (li).
```

use `mouseenter() \ mouseleave()`

```
`mouseenter` fires only when the pointer moves into the bound element.
```

**OR**

```
use `hover()`
```

here is the proper link that might help you to understand this

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm

Comment: your accept ratio is  0% ...  start accepting answer of your questions..so that u get help later from others.... :)..http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work... cheers..:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you `hide` the `ul` it has no area where the `mouseover` can be triggered. So you need to hold the area for get the mouseover. I have added ul in a div which has some width and height which is kept when ul got hide and binded events with this parent div.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UJ6vK/1/)**

*Html*

```
<div id="divId" style="widht:200px; height:200px;">
  <ul id='member'>
   <li>Change Villages ID#</li>
   <li>Change Address</li>
   <li>Changes Phone Numbers</li>
   <li>Change Name</</li>
  </ul>
</div>​
```

*Javascript*

```
$('#divId').mouseover (function() {
   // $('ul#member').css('background-color', 'silver');
    $('ul#member').show();
})

$('#divId').mouseout(function() {
   // $('ul#member').css('background-color', 'gray');
    $('ul#member').hide();

})​
```